# Where/how do I add this Bootstrap mid-small hack to my Bootstrap CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, responsive-design

I'd like to add this "hack" to my bootstrap enabled page (https://gist.github.com/Jakobud/c057577daddbde4dd709), however I'm completely new to Bootstrap and I'm not sure where to add the code. I know in the CSS folder I have bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css but if you click on the link above you can see it says for "SASS", and on line 15 it says: `// Instructions: Add the following to the end of bootstrap.scss`.

Comment: The code clearly states "SASS", which is **not** CSS. It's more like an instruction to a program on **how** to generate the CSS. Therefore, you can't use it directly without a parser.

Comment: @DanielCheung : I have already included the compiled & minified css file in my answer for UnluckyForSome to use in-case he stuck on compiling.

Answer (score -1):

## Download [Bootstrap with sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/archive/v3.3.7.tar.gz)

## Then follow the instruction of this [Tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-sass-installation-and-customisation/)

NOTE : Before compiling, add your custom sass file.

For your help, I have compiled the latest bootstrap with your custom sass file. Download the compiled minified version below.

[bootstrap.sass.min.css](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6s7fmo3y8j40bvo/bootstrap.sass.min.css?dl=0)

Comment: How would I add this without using installing SASS? I'd prefer to just use the plain bootstrap css!

Comment: You can't as that script has some dependencies. Unless you already have a compiled version of that file.

You can try some online compiler like [sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/) But there you will have to do a lot of works to find the dependencies and provide them to your script for compilation.

Comment: Oh right I see, could I use LESS if I change the $'s to @'s? That would be easier to implement. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: No, `Variables: from: $, to: @
Mixins: from: @mixin and @include, to: .
Import statements: cleaned up, but see below.
Remove all SASS !default declarations
Replace adjust-hue with spin
Replace fade-in with fadein
A ton of other "one-off" stuff`